# How can I display rows using column names without using a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

```
import mysql.connector

myDB = pymysql.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="exampleuser",
  password="examplepassword",
  database="exampledb"
)

myCursor = myDB.cursor(dictionary=True)
msg = "something"
SQL = "SELECT * FROM `example` WHERE `example`='" + msg + "'"
myCursor.execute(SQL)
myResult = myCursor.fetchall()

for row in myResult:
  print(row["example1"])
```

How can I do it like this:

```
row = someFunctionThatDoesWhatINeed(myResult)

print(row["example1"])
```

So, by this, I mean that I do not want to use `for` loop for the displaying the row's values using the column names.

### Edit:

Like in PHP:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row["example1"];
}
```

Or:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row["example1"];
```

I know that these loops are used for multiple rows. But, it will return only single rows. So, not use for loops, right?

Also, I will never use `fetchone()` instead of `fetchall()`. Don't suggest me examples containing `fetchone()`!

### IMPORTANT EDITS:

I cannot use any loops unnecessarily when I do not get multiple rows. So, do not suggest loops.

The List is:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'example.tld', 'domainId': '12345678_DOMAIN_tld-example', 'nsgroupId': 1, 'resellerId': 0, 'registrarId': 1, 'ownerHandle': '12242342432ABC', 'techHandle': '12242342432ABC', 'adminHandle': '12242342432ABC', 'billingHandle': '12242342432ABC', 'dnssec': 'unsigned', 'updatedDate': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 1, 1, 11, 39), 'creationDate': datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 1, 1, 11, 39), 'expirationDate': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 1, 1, 11, 39)}]
```

I want to display them like:

```
Domain Name: row[name] # Domain Name: example.tld
```

Comment: What is wrong with the `for` loop? It is the easiest, and one of the most effiecient (and pure python) ways of doing what you want.

Comment: @User12692182, I mean, I cannot use them each time when I use a different mysql connection in between.. un-necessary memory usage

Comment: What makes you think using loops causes unnecessary memory usage? Processing time maybe but not sure about memory usage.

Comment: @norie I even run mysql queries using the `row[example]`s returned. So, doing that inside a loop wouldn't be good right?

Comment: Why not do `myResult = myCursor.fetchone()` if you expect to receive only a single row?

Comment: @snakecharmerb, `LIMIT` in mysql vs `fetchone()`

Answer (score 0):

this is my approach:

> first convert mysql table into a pandas dataframe.

```
    import mysql.connector as sql

    import pandas as pd

    db_connection = sql.connect(host='hostname', database='db_name', user='username', password='password')

    db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()

    db_cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table_name')

    table_rows = db_cursor.fetchall()

    df = pd.DataFrame(table_rows)
```

> then display the rows using `df.iterrows` or `df.itertuples`

Comment: Any way without using extra `import`s?

Answer (score 0):

We've no idea what data is being returned by your query, but let's say there are 3 fields - id, name and address.

Perhaps something like this might work.

```
res =['Name Address']
res.extend([f'{name} {address}' for id, name, address in myResult])

print(res)
print('\n'.join(res))
```

Something like this might work - the first part get's the field names.

```
fields = map(lambda x:x[0], cursor.description)
result = [dict(zip(fields,row))   for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

Comment: I have about 8 fields... Just like you assumed. some personal data, but not passwords/usernames

Comment: The code I posted is pretty straightforward - replace id, name, address with the fields you want to display.

Comment: Isn't: `for id, name, address in myResult` a loop? I asked for code without any loops at all.

Comment: If you regard list comprehension as a loop then I'm afraid I can't see how this can be done without looping.